# If I run an application, ~/.application is created. Is it safe to delete?

Tags: files, settings, hidden-files

How do I stop it for creating such folders...
eg..if I open the application say - Stellarium, then
in the home - a folder ".Stellarium" gets created

This was not being created before...What can do to prevent such folders on being created. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 since 2 years.

Comment: Why do you want to delete it or prevent its creation?

Answer (score 2):

Those folders definitely *were* created before, but you probably hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> accidentally (the key combination to toggle visibility of folders and files with a name starting with a dot), so you can see them now.

#### What these folders are for

Usually applications store all kinds of (user specific-) settings & configuration files, profiles etc. in these hidden folders. In general, you can remove them safely, but then possibly changed settings, stored in such folders, will be lost. Also: on the next run, they simply will be re- created.

#### Be careful

Deleting these folders can however have bigger consequences: if you delete e.g. the folder `.thunderbird`, all your mail wil be lost.

#### Possible reasons to remove these directories

- Not really your question, but related: many times in case an application starts acting weird or with errors, removing (or temporarily renaming-) this folder is the first thing you would like to try, to force the application to recreate its settings file(s).
- Sometimes settings files of newer application versions are incompatible with older settings files. If you install a newer version of an application (e.g. when you upgrade your Ubuntu version), remaining outdated settings files can act up.
- If you have application settings of applications you don't use anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This folder contains your settings and preferences for that particular application. You can delete it if you really want, but the application will start with default settings.

If you are seeing these folders and don't want to, you have probably selected `Show Hidden Folders`. Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd> to toggle this.